# Dataframe filter to set no value found to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, exception

Is there a solution to set this operation to 0 value without using try except block?

```
try:
   op = df[df['a'] == "ABC"] 
except Exception:
   op = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're catching the exception in case `'a'` is not a column in `df`.

You can test for the column's existence like this:

```
if 'a' in df.columns:
    op = df[df['a'] == "ABC"]
else:
    op = 0
```

or as a one-liner:

```
op = df[df['a'] == "ABC"] if 'a' in df.columns else 0
```

If you are actually wanting to set `op` to `0` if `"ABC"` is not found, you can test whether the resulting dataframe is empty:

```
op = df[df['a'] == "ABC"]
if op.empty:
    op = 0
```